# I have json objects inside a json array but a long try i did not found a good result

Tags: java, android, json

I want to parse and get them store in a arraylist to show in a spinner with single text as a company location in android.I am a fresher in android and don't know how 
I have this json file coming from a url:

```
   {

GetCompanyLocationResult:
 {

LoginMessage:

 {

ErrorMsg: null,

Success: true

},

UserLocation: [

{

Comp_Location: "ABCD-ABCD"

},

{

Comp_Location: "CBS-DELHI"

},

{

Comp_Location: "CBS-JAIPUR"

},

{

Comp_Location: "CBS-MEERUT"

},
{
Comp_Location: "CBS-NOIDA"

},

{

Comp_Location: "CBS-RAJASTHAN"

},

{

Comp_Location: "MISAP-DELHI"

},

{

Comp_Location: "MISAP-NOIDA"

},

{

Comp_Location: "SYNERGY-DELHI"

}

]

}

}
```

Comment: Please send me the code . Thanks in advance

Comment: _Please send me the code_ This is clearly not how SO works. You should take a [tour] to learn about this community. See [ask] and then edit your question. Without some effort (visible effort) from you, this will not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> your json is not valid json please check your json [here](http://jsonlint.com/)

Answer (score 0):

valid JSON like below :

```
{
    "GetCompanyLocationResult": {
        "LoginMessage": {
            "ErrorMsg": null,
            "Success": true
        },
        "UserLocation": [{
                "Comp_Location": "ABCD-ABCD"
            },
            {
                "Comp_Location": "CBS-DELHI"
            },
            {
                "Comp_Location": "CBS-JAIPUR"
            },
            {
                "Comp_Location": "CBS-MEERUT"
            },
            {
                "Comp_Location": "CBS-NOIDA"
            },
            {
                "Comp_Location": "CBS-RAJASTHAN"
            },
            {
                "Comp_Location": "MISAP-DELHI"
            },
            {
                "Comp_Location": "MISAP-NOIDA"
            },
            {
                "Comp_Location": "SYNERGY-DELHI"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

key name should be in "" mark.
EX--> "GetCompanyLocationResult":{} Instead Of GetCompanyLocationResult:{}

Answer (score 0):

Try this..it will save userLocations in ArrayList

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        JSONObject obj = null;
        try {
            obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            JSONObject obj1 = obj.getJSONObject("GetCompanyLocationResult");
            JSONArray jArray = obj1.getJSONArray("UserLocation");


            for (int i = 0; i <= jArray.length(); i++) {
                arrayList.add(jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Comp_Location"));
                System.out.println(arrayList.get(i).toString() + "\n");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. You saved my life.

Comment: if it solve your problem than you can upvote or mark this answer as correct

Answer (score -2):

@Om Prakash try the below code:

```
private void test(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    ArrayList<String> companyNameArray = new ArrayList<>();
    if (jsonObject.has("GetCompanyLocationResult")) {
        try {
            JSONObject comapnyLocationObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("GetCompanyLocationResult");
            if (comapnyLocationObject.has("UserLocation")) {
                 Object obj = comapnyLocationObject.get("UserLocation");
                if (obj instanceof JSONArray) {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) obj;
                    for (int index = 0; index < jsonArray.length(); index++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonComapny = jsonArray.getJSONObject(index);
                            if (jsonComapny.has("Comp_Location")) {
                                companyNameArray.add(jsonComapny.getString("Comp_Location"));
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why -1 just let me know what's the issue before downvoting. Its just you need to first validate your json whether its proper or not.You can use json lint for the same. Otherwise the parsing required is as above mentioned

Comment: @Om please up vote the answer if it worked for you

Comment: you didn't get the JSONArray  "UserLocation" and your code has a lot of unnecessary if blocks.

Comment: @AkshayMore i have fetched the "UserLocation" and have first checked whether the object is a JSONArray or JSONObject. Take a look at the code above.And to keep code cleaner it should be followed by blocks

Comment: `JSONArray jsonArray =comapnyLocationObject.getJSONArray("UserLocation"); ` find me this line in your code, you have `Object obj = jsonObject;`  
`JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) obj;`  `jsonObject` was passed as an argument.

Comment: since I don't have 125 reputations I cannot downvote an answer, I just provided an explanation. Review your code before posting or after being downvoted.

Comment: Thanks @AkshayMore have updated it